# How to map list of Triple into data class with nested list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Sample

```
val listTriple = listOf<Triple<Int, Int, String>>()
```

```
data class Sample(val parentId: Int, val listItem : List<Item>)
```

```
data class Item(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

how to map `listTriple` into `listOf` `Sample` in kotlin in the best way

Comment: in your triple. which one is the `parentId` and which one is the `id` ?

Comment: I kinda feel like you should have made a class for that Triple in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You can express that really concise by specifying [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html)s `valueTransform` lambda:

```
val samples = listTriple.groupBy({ it.first }, { Item(it.second, it.third) }).map {
  Sample(it.key, it.value)
}
```

But as EpicPandaForce mentioned in the comments it would be better to create a dedidacted class instead of using `Triple`. Having to refer to properties by `first`, `second`, `third` makes it hard to read.

Of course I could've just destructuring syntax here as well, but that doesn't solve the problem of not having a dedicated class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first `Int` of your triple is the `parentId` and the second one is the `id`, you would do this:

```
val listOfSample = listTriple.map {(parentId, id, name) ->
            Sample(parentId, listOf(Item(id, name)))
        }
```

If they are in the other order, just change the order in the '.map{}'

You can do groupBy for the secondary question of `how to concatenate all lists based on the same parent id`

```
val listOfSample = listTriple.map {(parentId, id, name) ->
            Sample(parentId, listOf(Item(id, name)))
        }.groupBy { it.parentId }
```

Comment: how to concatenate all lists based on the same parent id

Comment: This is a different question and should be part of the initial question. Nevertheless, you do that by adding `.groupBy { it.parentId }` at the end, and you will have a `map<parentId, list<Sample>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val samples = list
            .groupBy { it.first }
            .map {
                val items = it.value.map { Item(it.second, it.third) }
                Sample(it.key, items)
            }
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between this and the answer I posted (except that you had the extra info that I wrote in the comment once the second question was posed in the comment of that answer).

Comment: The result of `groupBy{}.map{}` is different than `map{}.groupBy{}`.

Comment: `groupBy{}.map{}` will return list of samples.